# Android navigation bar overlay

Tags: android, layoutparams, android-windowmanager

For my application I have to draw a bitmap on top of the Navigation bar on the bottom of the android screen. I am curious to know if the  WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY can be used to overlay the navigation bar?

Comment: "I have to draw a bitmap on top of the Navigation bar on the bottom of the android screen" -- what will you do when the bar is not on the bottom of the screen, but rather on the side? What will you do for devices that do not have this bar? What will you do for devices where the height of the bar changes based on external factors, such as being plugged into HDMI? And why would interfering with the navigation bar this way be in the user's best interests?

Comment: @CommonsWare What if you want implement application in kiosk mode? Android does not allow this out of the box, and UX navigation capabilities is not a matter in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS` should work :)

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I fixed it by adding an offset in YPOS equal to the height of the navigation bar while defining the Windowmanager Layoutparams.

Comment: FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS does not even draw on top of the status bar. FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN draws on top of the status bar, but not on top of the navigation bar. Tested with API 23 (Marshmallow).